# Confused with the answer to the real analysis question

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

$X$ is any set,
$R=\{X, \emptyset\}$. $\mu$ is the following measure：$\mu(X)= \infty$ and $\mu(\emptyset)=0$.
The question is：
What are the corresponding $\mu^*$-measurable sets $R^*$(that is, Carathéodory-measurable sets) according to the Caratheodory's Extension Theorem?
The answer is :
$R^*=R$,with the outer measures $\mu^*=\mu$.
But I think $R^*$ should be "All the subsets of $X$", because any $E \subseteq X$ meet the condition of Caratheodory：$\mu^*(F)=\mu^*(F \cap E)+\mu^*(F \setminus E)$ , for all $F \in 2^X$.
Am I wrong? Where is my error?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Please, learn to format properly your question.  This time I helped formatting your question.

Comment: You are right. Suppose $X$ is not empty. We have that $\mu^*$ is defined on $2^X$ and for any $A \neq \emptyset$, $\mu^*(A)=\infty$. Since $\mu$ is defined only on $\{\emptyset , X\}$, clearly $\mu^* \ne \mu$.  Now, given any $E \subseteq X$, it is easy to see that, for all $F \in 2^X$,  $\mu^*(F)=\mu^*(F \cap E)+\mu^*(F \setminus E)$. So, $E$ is $\mu^*$-measurable. So $R^*=2^X$.